# Atheros AR9485 behaviour is broken after update to 15.10

Tags: networking, 15.10, atheros, ath9k

So, I updated to 15.10 from 14.10 and now I have to deal with major WiFi shenanigans.

It is not blocked. It sees all the networks clearly. I can see it in `nmcli` and `iwconfig`.

So, if I try to connect with WRONG password it naturally asks for password again.
But if I connect using right password, it just tries to connect for a while and gives up without any observable reason.

FYI the router is not the case, I post this from my tablet using this router, and at the same time Ubuntu can't connect to it.

I could post `lshw` or `iwconfig` results as the whole, but it would be hard considering I can't copy paste. So, in `nmcli d show` wlan0 is WiFi with Mac, mtu of zero, disconnected. In `lshw -C network` Wireless Interface AR9845 Qualcomm Atheros wlan0 have a width of 64 bits, a clock of 33MHz, capabilities of `pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical wireless` and a configuration of `broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=3.16.0-39-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn`.
`iwconfig` shows that wlan0 ESSID is off/any, mode is managed, access point isn't associated, retry short limit is 7, RTS the is off, fragment the is off and power management is off too.

And none of it is telling me what is going on.

Update: I changed kernel to 4.3.0, it didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it seems there are problems with drivers or whatsoever.
After changing the kernel I did further investigation.
I tried to connect with `nmcli d wifi connect SSID` and it told me:
`Error: Connection activation failed: (5) IP configuration could not be reserved (no available address, timeout, etc.).`
I checked the logs on wifi router from my tablet and what I saw is this:

```
[WLAN access rejected: incorrect security] from MAC address 6c:71:d9:56:b7:41, Sunday, December 06,2015 19:48:10
[DHCP IP: 192.168.1.4] to MAC address 6c:71:d9:56:b7:41, Sunday, December 06,2015 19:35:22
```

So, what I did was set my IPv4 config to manual and it suddenly worked. Why the router told me about wrong security, and why my laptop didn't actually remember IP address which was distributed to it with DHCP are still complete mysteries to me, possibly a bug.

It's hardly an answer, just a workaround, but from this I recommend to connect through console using `nmcli` and read what it tells you, if you are experiencing troubles with connection.

Answer (score 0):

You have a wrong kernel for Ubuntu 15.10. Are you usre yiu have 15.10, not 15.04? If you are sure, install kernel 4.2 by running:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic
```

Comment: How can I do this without internet connection? Can I  revert the update first,  then update the kernel, and update again?

Comment: There is no way to "revert update". You can connect to internet by wire, or download kernel packages manually. The easiest way for you is to do a fresh install of 15.10.

Comment: I have installed kernel 4.3, and ath9k driver version is now 4.3.0. The problem is still persists. Of course, it can be the case I must install exactly 4.2 kernel, but honestly it doesn't seem the problem is with the kernel.